# loading custom registration template

Tags: user-registration, template-hierarchy

I read [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialstag.com/create-custom-wordpress-registration-page.html), here the author names the template `custom-register.php` and puts it in the theme dir and doesn't explain about how it's loaded by WP, I did the same way but the file didn't loaded on request to the WP signup.

What's the trick here?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to link that page in your functions page

require_once('custom-register.php')

```
cp_head(__('Register','cp'));
    ?>
        <?php cp_show_errors($errors); ?>
       <div class="alert alert"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>Welcome: </strong> 
            <?php _e('Complete the fields below to become a member.', 'cp') ?>
          </div>

       <div class="alert alert-info"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>Information: </strong> 
            <?php _e('Your password will be mailed to you so use valid email address.', 'cp') ?>
          </div>
        <div class="row">
<form class="loginform" name="registerform" id="registerform" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" method="post">
        <div class="span4">
       <label>Username</label>
      <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="user_login" type="text" id="focusedInput" value="<?php echo attribute_escape(stripslashes($user_login)); ?>"  /> 
      </div>


        <div class="span4"> 

     <label>Email</label>
      <input class="input-xlarge focused" name="user_email" type="email" id="focusedInput" value="<?php echo attribute_escape(stripslashes($user_email)); ?>"  />

      </div>

         <div class="span4"> 
    <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
      <input class="btn btn-success" name="wp-submit" value="Send" type="submit" style="height:52px; width:280px;" />
      </div>

</form>
</div>
        <?php cp_footer_div() ?>
```

Should give you an output like http://www.evo3dmovies.com/wp-login.php?action=register

Comment: if I directly link to the template, how can I use wp features (like $user_id, wp_create_user(), ...) in the template without loading of wp core?

Comment: The page you have created you need to link to functions php and let wordpress do the rest. Dont directly link to the page.

Comment: sorry, i need a little more explanation, You mean functions.php in wp-includes? and how should I link to my page in that file, so on the signup request my page loaded? thanks

Comment: No the functions.php in your theme folder. I told you how to link it in the answer above. require_once('custom-register.php');

Comment: ok, i didn't know when you request wp-login.php, the functions.php of the theme also loaded, so in functions.php I need to check the `action` query var for including the 'custom-register.php`?

Comment: also after including my custom-register page, the form of built-in registration is put in the page, Should i `exit` at the end of my custom-register page to prevent this or there is more decent way to do this?

Comment: What are you using for the registration page? Whats the code?